# Add a link to the accepted answer when it was by the OP

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, usability, self-answer

While it's fair to *not* make an own answer the most prominent one after self-acceptance, in questions with many answers it is still difficult to find if it is not also the most up-voted one, e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/14224/how-to-explain-drm-cannot-work/14764#14764). So a small `jump to the OP's self-accepted answer` link (or maybe a `show the (self-!)-accepted answer`-button to expand the answer at the top) would be nice.

**edit** Technically, it's already possible, using the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=): `inquestion:this isaccepted:1`

Comment: I can't imagine this feature ever being implemented. If the admins wanted any kind of indication of an accepted answer at the top of the answers list, they'd have just left the accepted answer there. Moving the answer but giving a notification and a link is a lose-lose.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

This would require coding first and foremost, and if the OP's self accepted answer is not the highest voted one, it means that the highest voted one is the most general and reasonable answer?

Also, based on the premise that quesitons are updated with new and fresh information, some accepted answers could become outdated overtime if not adjusted by the OP. Which is rare to happen. So therefore votes should be the highest donominator in this whole process.

Also, I am pretty certain that there is no more then 5% of question on SO that are self answered. But I will give credit to the stats guys who can give exact figures.

Comment: I view by oldest first, so the first two points are invalid.

Comment: @Thomas Fair enough, however, I still don't feel there is enough self answered questions to validate this requirement.

Comment: Accepted answers by others also don't necessarily get updated, in any case this should be commented on by others if observed. And sometimes I'm not only interested in the highest voted answer (I am, but not *only*), but also into what turned out to actually help the OP since I may happen to have made the same mistake which can be fixed in exactly the same manner - while still the higher-voted answers deserve more up-votes for being more applicable in general

Comment: @Tobias. Still think it's extra work for an edge case. But thankfully, the community can vote on this and prove me wrong :) Which if that's the case I will happily throw in my vote.

Comment: ♦: But it's already possible, using the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=): `inquestion:this isaccepted:1`